# Make nginx accept requests only from a specific server

Tags: nginx, networking, configuration

I want to configure an nginx server to accept HTTP requests only from a specific server.

I am not sure if this should be accomplished through the `listen` directive, or by using `allow`/`deny` rules in `location`. Or another method that I am not aware of.

When trying to find documentation about `listen`, I haven't found an example that uses an actual external IP, only stuff like localhost or other interfaces.

Is what I want even possible with `listen`? Or is `allow`/`deny` the better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be focussing on restricting access by IP address - and even static IP addresses aren't permanent. There are better ways to go about this but they are a little involved (shared secret, VPN, client certs).

Yes, you can use the [allow/deny rules](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html). These can be in the location block, the server block or even the http block.

Comment: I am aware of the caveats, however the only way for this to be done right now is using the IP. Do you know if it could also be done with `listen`? (this was also part of my question)

Comment: The IP address option on the Listen directive specifies which LOCAL ip address nginx should accept connections on - so unless you have some very esoteric networking going on (e.g. a VPN) then this doesn't help.